# Why is this "not an answer" flag rejected?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

[The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487073/2333214):

> I'm loading elements via ajax. Some of them are only visible if you scroll down the page.
>   Is there any way I can know if an element is now in the visible part of the page?
>
> EDIT: freakytard solution was right, but I modified it a bit to also
>   check if element is wholly visible
>
> ```
> function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
> var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
> var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
>
> var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
> var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
>
> return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
>   && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
> ```
>
> }

[Original *freakytard* solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/2333214):

> This should do the trick:
>
> ```
> function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
> {
>     var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
>     var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
>     var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
>     var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
>     return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
> }
> ```

[The flagged answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7125552/2333214):

> An answer to your update:
>
> ```
>  return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
>      && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
> ```
>
> is the same as the shorter:
>
> ```
>  return ( (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
> ```

It claims it is an **answer**. I flagged it as "not an answer", which is rejected.

I usually go through the answers when I happen to visit a *famous old* post, and flag the unwanted stuff posted as an answer. But the issue is, the post being *famous*, every 2-3 year old responses might have few upvotes. Probably because of that reason, reviewers tend to reject it, they might be even thinking it's an audit seeing the upvotes (*My guess*).

I tried flagging it again hoping to find other reviewers but the system doesn't allow that.

Is that an answer? Shouldn't it be a comment to the question? Or am i totally wrong?

Comment: Why is that answer not an answer?  It looks like an answer to me.

Comment: It simply states the `OP`'s modification is same as the original answer. It is just criticising the OP's modification, the answer is already there. doesn't answer the original question at all...

Comment: Your flag was disputed by the review queue - the community felt it was an answer and disagreed with your flag. Possibly if you left a comment stating what reason you felt it wasn't an answer the decision _may_ have been different.

Comment: @bluefeet did you mean, below the answer..?

Comment: It's answering a follow up question that was edited into the original question, without answering the original question.  That doesn't make it NAA.

Comment: @TJ If you added a comment under that answer on why it shouldn't be an answer the reviewers might have taken that into consideration.  At this point, it looks to be an answer which is probably why they disagreed with your flag.

Comment: @Servy I don't see any follow up question... The post just criticizes the OP's modification saying that it is still the same as the accepted answer... it doesn't answer the question or any follow up question. i thought that should be done in comments...

Comment: It may not be an answer, but it does look like one - particularly when reviewing flags as the question isn't shown there.

Comment: For the love of obfuscation, please stop inventing 3 letter abbreviations!

Comment: @Lundin What? You don't like TLAs? ;)

Comment: @RetoKoradi TLA;DR

Comment: BTW: An edit war is going on for the question..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your flag wasn't declined, it was disputed.

That means that a moderator didn't claim you were wrong; members of the community did.

It has been declined before; but that was back in 2011; and you weren't the flagger then.

Without a flag that tells us:

- Why it's not an answer
- What we should do with it
- If it's not an answer, where should it go? under another post? The question? No where?

We can't really do much about it.  It makes my spidey sense tingle, but not enough to be able to determine where it should go. The onus for that is on the flagger.

Our default rule is to keep content around unless there's a clear and convincing case for why it should be deleted. [That wasn't provided here, according to the community](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5822327).

Comment: I Added a comment below it. Hope the original poster take necessary action or somebody flags it again and the reviewers see my comment... :)